# XL-deploy specification - what does this security spec do?

Tags: maven-plugin, xl-deploy, deployit

Using Maven, XL-deploy and Deployit, I want to focus extra on security on the intranet.

In examples I see the following maven, xl-deploy scripts. **I have marked it with **** start ... till ... **** end.**

What does it accomplish? Security for intranet and/or internet? I have been scanning the documentation for a while.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.xebialabs.xldeploy</groupId>
      <artifactId>xldeploy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          ...
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <username>user-xyz</username>
          <password>password-xyz</password>
          <serverAddress>server-address</serverAddress>
          <environmentId>Environments/app-1</environmentId>                      
          <deployables>
           ************ start 
            <deployable>
              <name>AD-role1</name>
              <type>AD.AddRol</type>
              <rol>role1,role2</rol>
           </deployable>
           ************ end
```

Do you also have a document reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML code here instructs Maven to build a Deployment Archive for XL Deploy.  The marked code is one element of the package, a deployable object of type AD.AddRol, to be deployed, I presume, to an AD server to create a role named AD-role-1, or perhaps roles named role1 and role2.  This appears to be a custom extension to the XL Deploy product, so the deployment details must be inferred.  See https://docs.xebialabs.com/xldeploy-maven-plugin/6.0.x/ for the plugin documentation.  See https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/ for general information about XL Deploy's model-based deployment type system.